# How do you wrap a C function that returns a pointer to a malloc'd array with ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a C function that reads a binary file and returns a dynamically sized array of unsigned integers (the size is based off metadata from the binary file):

```
//example.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__declspec(dllexport)unsigned int *read_data(char *filename, size_t* array_size){
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
  fread(array_size, sizeof(size_t), 1, f);
  unsigned int *array = (unsigned int *)malloc(*array_size * sizeof(unsigned int));
  fread(array, sizeof(unsigned int), *array_size, f);
  fclose(f);

  return array;
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913932/ctypes-fast-way-to-convert-a-return-pointer-to-an-array-or-python-list) appears to be saying that the correct way to pass the created array from C to Python is something like this:

```
# example_wrap.py
from ctypes import *
import os

os.add_dll_directory(os.getcwd())
indexer_dll = CDLL("example.dll")

def read_data(filename):
    filename = bytes(filename, 'utf-8')
    size = c_size_t()
    ptr = indexer_dll.read_data(filename, byref(size))
    return ptr[:size]
```

However, when I run the python wrapper, the code silently fails at `ptr[:size]` as if I'm trying to access an array out of bounds, and I probably am, but what is the correct way to pass this dynamically size array?

Comment: Where is the definition of `indexer_dll.read_index()` that you are calling in your python code?

Comment: In the C code posted. Oh sorry, I was renaming and reducing my code to make it more generic and I missed changing that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few considerations:

First, you need to properly set the prototype of the C function so that ctypes can properly convert between the C and Python types.

Second, since `size` is actually a `ctypes.c_size_t` object, you actually need to use `size.value` to access the numeric value of the array size.

Third, since `ptr[:size.value]` actually copies the array contents to a Python list, you'll want to make sure you also `free()` the allocated C array since you're not going to use it anymore.

(Perhaps copying the array to a Python list is not ideal here, but I'll assume it's ok here, since otherwise you have more complexity in handling the C array in Python.)

This should work:

```
from ctypes import *
import os

os.add_dll_directory(os.getcwd())
indexer_dll = CDLL("example.dll")
indexer_dll.read_data.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(c_size_t)
indexer_dll.read_data.restype = POINTER(c_int)
libc = cdll.msvcrt

def read_data(filename):
    filename = bytes(filename, 'utf-8')
    size = c_size_t()
    ptr = indexer_dll.read_data(filename, byref(size))
    result = ptr[:size.value]
    libc.free(ptr)
    return result
```

Comment: Well you solved the problem I asked for, thank you. It is failing silently at libc.free(ptr).

Comment: Probably msvcrt is using a different library. I fixed it by creating a free_mem C function and calling it through the dll.

Comment: @CSStudent7782 Yeah I tested it on Linux (where you actually load `libc.so`), on Windows it's quite possibly different... Exporting your own function will surely work!