# Ctypes arrays, performance of converting pointer to double pointer to python list

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance, ctypes

Following c-DLL header

```
    int getDoubleArray(double const** const value);
```

where the return value is the size of the double array, created in the function.

I'm able to receive the data. But now I would like to convert it to a Python list object (not able to use NumPy here, because of legacy reasons)

After calling the function

```
    ## val_arr is a POINTER to c_double
    ## x contains the size of the array (count of doubles)
    x = getDoubleArrayFunc (byref(val_arr))
```

I tried 2 ways to convert it to a Python list

```
## noob approach
values = []
for i in range(x):
    values.append(val_arr[i])
## better (?) approach
values2 = [val_arr[i] for i in range(x)]
```

I tested it with a list of 20000 entries
the second approach is about 1/3 faster  ~1ms vs 1.6 ms

Now the question: is there another way to improve performance (without using numpy or other external libs)?

It should run with Python 3.x (at least 3.7 or newer)

Comment: As the duplicate indicates, use `val_arr[:size]`.  Slicing the ctypes pointer will return a list of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was already answered some time ago
[Ctypes: fast way to convert a return pointer to an array or Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913932/ctypes-fast-way-to-convert-a-return-pointer-to-an-array-or-python-list)

Results after 1000 times converting a list with 20000 entries (in sek)

- convert duration:  1.6180373
- convert2 duration:  1.0428218
- convert3 duration:  0.33130780000000026
- convert4 (numpy) duration:  0.00794270000000008, here I explicity do a deepcopy into a new memory